# UITableView section header doesn't float in grouped table iOS9

Tags: ios, uitableview, header

Anyone else have this problem? I've tried loading a view from xib, reusing a table cell view, creating a new UIView directly in code, same result every time. Even though table is grouped, the header doesn't float. I'm returning the height for the header as required and this works fine, it's just the floating that doesn't work (and I wants it!).. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the default behaviour of a grouped Tableview. Headers and footers float only for `UITableViewStylePlain`.

Comment: WTF I thought it was the default behavior for plain... I wanted plain all along!